# How to impute each categorical column in numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

There are good solutions to impute panda dataframe. But since I am working mainly with numpy arrays, I have to create new panda DataFrame object, impute and then convert back to numpy array as follows:

```
nomDF=pd.DataFrame(x_nominal) #Convert np.array to pd.DataFrame
nomDF=nomDF.apply(lambda x:x.fillna(x.value_counts().index[0])) #replace NaN with most frequent in each column
x_nominal=nomDF.values #convert back pd.DataFrame to np.array
```

Is there a way to directly impute in numpy array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use [`Scipy's mode`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mstats.mode.html) to get the highest value in each column. Leftover work would be to get the `NaN` indices and replace those in input array with the `mode` values by indexing.

So, the implementation would look something like this -

```
from scipy.stats import mode

R,C = np.where(np.isnan(x_nominal))
vals = mode(x_nominal,axis=0)[0].ravel()
x_nominal[R,C] = vals[C]
```

Please note that for `pandas`, with `value_counts`, we would be choosing the highest value in case of many categories/elements with the same highest count. i.e. in tie situations. With `Scipy's mode`, it would be lowest one for such tie cases.

If you are dealing with such mixed dtype of `strings` and `NaNs`, I would suggest few modifications, keeping the last step unchanged to make it work -

```
x_nominal_U3 = x_nominal.astype('U3')
R,C = np.where(x_nominal_U3=='nan')
vals = mode(x_nominal_U3,axis=0)[0].ravel()
```

This throws a warning for the mode calculation : `RuntimeWarning: The input array could not be properly checked for nan values. nan values will be ignored.
  "values. nan values will be ignored.", RuntimeWarning)`. But since, we actually want to ignore `NaNs` for that mode calculation, we should be okay there.

Comment: My array is **nominal**. That is, e.g. 
array([['a', 'g', 's', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'],
       [nan, 'j', 'w', 't', 'i', 'k', 'l'],
       ['b', 'r', 't', 'u', 'c', 'g', 'h'],
       ['x', 'i', 'w', 'h', 'k', 'd', nan]], dtype=object)

with 
   > **R,C = np.where(np.isnan(a))**

I get:
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''**