# Python package to use mode

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, mode

I need the mode function to rank a classifier and the code below is where the mode function is needed to get the ranking.

class VoteClassifier(ClassifierI):
    def **init**(self, *classifiers):
        self._classifiers = classifiers

```
def classify(self, features):
    votes = []
    for c in self._classifiers:
        v = c.classify(features)
        votes.append(v)
    return mode(votes)

def confidence(self, features):
    votes = []
    for c in self._classifiers:
        v = c.classify(features)
        votes.append(v)

    choice_votes = votes.count(mode(votes))
    conf = choice_votes / len(votes)
    return conf
```

This is the import i am using [image]. However i get this error [image] The answer for the question posted here doesn't seem to help ([How to impute each categorical column in numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39462449/how-to-impute-each-categorical-column-in-numpy-array)). When i searched on the web there is this straight forward mode for python 3 but does not seem to work on python 2.7 this import is shown below,

```
from statistics import mode
```

Is there any other package that has mode functionality for this purpose or any method to rectify this error?

Comment: Can you create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem?  Also, please add the *complete* error message (i.e. the full traceback) to the question.  Finally, can you show what `type(v)` is?  (Perhaps just `print type(v)` in the loop.)

Comment: That is the complete error it is a run time error.  I don't think you understand the classify function combined with feature set. However, V are the features of the text like "pos", "neg".

Comment: You're right--I realized my comment about showing the traceback was not relevant after making the comment.

Answer (score 1):

To compute the mode you can use the [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) in the [`Collections`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html) package which has a mode function. Exactly, use [most common](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common). Here is an example:

```
from collections import Counter
data = Counter(your_list)
data.most_common()   # All unique items with their counts
data.most_common(1)  # The highest occurring item: the mode
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I tried to use your solution it doesn't seem to work. however this is what i tried.                                                           def classify(self, features):
        votes = []
        for c in self._classifiers:
            v = c.classify(features)
            votes.append(v)
            count=Counter(votes)
            v=count.most_common(1)
        return v